# Java web service - when to use XmlAttribute?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wsdl, jax-ws, marshalling

Having a halo class with fields like that:

```
private String description;   // a lot of text
private long price;
private int count;
```

.. I found that for `price` and `count` `@XmlAttribute` was used, but not for the `description`.
Why?

What is the difference and how/where are they stored?

Answer (score 1):

very good article on [IBM's website](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-eleatt/index.html)

> If the information in question could be itself marked up with
>   elements, put it in an element.
>
> If the information is suitable for attribute form, but could end up as
>   multiple attributes of the same name on the same element, use child
>   elements instead.
>
> If the information is required to be in a standard DTD-like attribute
>   type such as ID, IDREF, or ENTITY, use an attribute.
>
> If the information should not be normalized for white space, use
>   elements. (XML processors normalize attributes in ways that can change
>   the raw text of the attribute value.)

Comment: I suggest, giving at-least required information from that website as a answer and giving link to website. In-case if link become outdated entire answer will become invalid

Answer (score 0):

Both XmlElement  and @XmlAttribute are quite self-documenting.

@XmlElement will be serialized as an Xml Element (Child node of the current node)

@XmlAttribute will be serialized as an Xml attribute.

knowbody's answer is quite clear about when choose one or the other.

So in your example, you should get something like

```
<halo price="..." count="..." >
    <description>...</description>
</halo>
```